# Select2 preloading data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Currently select2 only loads data once user starts typing. I want to preload the drop down with some default values, so once the user clicks on the drop down there are already some values to select from.. I've looked at the documentation but I couldn't find anything. Does anybody know if there is a workaround or something I could do to achieve this.

Thank you

Edit:

```
$('#search-paint').select2({
                placeholder: "Search By:Manufacturer, Color Name, Color Code",
                ajax: {
                    url: "/item/searchPaint",
                    dataType: "json",
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term,
                            SprayType: $('#spray-type').val(),
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        params.page = params.page || 1;
                        return {
                            results: data.items.data,
                            pagination: {
                                more: (data.items.current_page * data.items.per_page) < data.items.total
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                    return markup;
                },
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                templateResult: formatRepo,
                templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
            });
```

I've tried preloading data using the `data` setting, but it only loads the first object and is calls the select method. I've also tried `initSelection` but later I discovered it has a different purpose from what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I've added some code and a bit more information

Comment: You can simply have `option` tags in your select before you apply select2

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
var data = [];
$('#search-paint').select2({
    data:data,
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
       return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
$.getJSON('/item/searchPaint',function(response){
    data=response;
    $('#search-paint').select2('refresh');
});
```